# How to Find Dominant colors in an image in c++ and percentage of each cluster?

Tags: c++

I am able to  get the dominant color from image, but I am not able to get the percentage of color.

This is my code to get the dominant color from a image:

```
cv::Matsource_img=cv::imread("detect.bmp",1); // Read image from path

// Serialize, float
cv::Mat data = source_img.reshape(1, source_img.total());
data.convertTo(data, CV_32F);
// Perform k-Means
int k = 10;
std::vector<int> labels;
cv::Mat3f centers;
cv::kmeans(data, k, labels, cv::TermCriteria(), 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,   centers);

// Make a poster! (Clustering)
for (int i = 0; i < (int)labels.size(); ++i) {
    data.at<float>(i, 0) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 0);
    data.at<float>(i, 1) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 1);
    data.at<float>(i, 2) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 2);
   // qDebug()<<labels.size();
}
// Un-Serialize, un-float
cv::Mat destination = data.reshape(3, source_img.rows);
destination.convertTo(source_img, CV_8UC3);
std::sort(centers.begin(), centers.end(),
        [](const cv::Vec3f &a, const cv::Vec3f &b) -> bool
        { return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] > b[0] + b[1] + b[2]; }
    );
// Paint!
QLabel *palette[6] = {ui->b_1, ui->b_2, ui->b_3, ui->b_4, ui->b_5, ui->b_6};
const int p = 0; // Offset
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    // Set back color of label. Lazy ass way to show the colors
    std::stringstream back_clr;
    back_clr << centers.at<float>(i + p, 2) << "," << centers.at<float>(i + p, 1) << "," << centers.at<float>(i + p, 0);
    palette[i]->setStyleSheet(QString::fromStdString("background-color:rgb(" + back_clr.str() + ");"));
    qInfo()<< QString::fromStdString(back_clr.str() );
}
```

This is my output:

```
Screenshot from 2021-04-09 16-51-30.png

"238.594,229.237,205.951"
"213.832,204.984,180.845"
"216.373,190.585,84.8002"
"218.931,132.845,105.804"
"138.95,143.804,118.714"
"198.743,110.853,46.7355"
```

But I want the output like this:

```
[238.59435545 229.23386034 205.94674433] 29.34%
[213.67154468 204.84374578 180.77144429] 21.07%
[198.76836914 110.87256368 46.76773957] 7.76%
[39.94140346 42.37245936 36.42510903] 7.68%
[216.17736047 190.52489076 84.93423309] 7.36%
[ 83.247557 108.82634188 70.66370203] 7.15%
[82.05183941 60.05586475 55.07991179] 5.87%
[218.7735931 132.99684942 105.99257623] 5.62%
[ 41.73549837 87.24996989 139.9000843 ] 5.07%
[132.72742222 139.51450372 113.63158587] 3.09%
```

Comment: "I am not able" is not a problem description. What have you tried to get the percentage? In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count how often each individual label occurs in `labels`, i.e. label `0` occurs 29.34% in `labels`. That's just a `std::count` divided by `labels.size()`

Comment: how to get the count values? @MSalters

Comment: @sachin: As I said, use `std::count`.

Comment: how to get the count of all the labels@MSalters

Comment: able to get the percentage now sort based on percentage@MSalters